# Guzzle post give 403 - Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse whereas Postman works

Tags: laravel, post, guzzle

I'm making a post request with postman that works:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ZjLWMyMmItNDk1MS04ZjQzLTNlZmM1NDAyZjkzZA==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I'm trying to do it with Laravel 8:

```
$res = Http::withBasicAuth("user", "***")
            ->withOptions([
                'debug' => true,
                'verify' => false])
            ->withHeaders([
                "Content-Type"=> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ])
            ->post(env("URL") . "/v1/oauth2/token", [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
                ]
            ]);
```

And I get a `403 Forbidden`

In debug information, I get:

```
Content-Length: 51 * upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error < Cache-Control: no-cache < Connection: close < Pragma: no-cache < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 < Content-Length: 77 < * Closing connection 0
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
$res = Http::asForm()
            ->withBasicAuth("user", "***")
            ->withOptions([
                'verify' => false
            ])
            ->post(env("URL") . "/v1/oauth2/token", [
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
                
            ]);
```